# Using a custom folder for "File Search" Launch Condition in VS Installer (VS 2010)

Tags: .net, installation, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a setup file for my solution in VS2010. It's a C# application. So far it does whatever I need. However, I do some Interop stuff and this setup file shouldn't be run unless some Native DLLs exist on the system. I tried using the "File Search" Launch Condition type to try and find this file before I launch the installer, but it only seems to work for the special folders it lists in the combo box in the "Folder" Property for the File Search Launch Condition. Is there any way I can do what I need with the VS Setup Project?

I need to check if a file in C:\MYFOLDER\ exists before I let the setup continue. Is this possible through VS Installer?

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the folder to:

```
[WindowsVolume]MyFolder
```

WindowsVolume property is resolved automatically to "C:\"

Comment: Hey,I tried several variations of that, but still nothing. I tried [WindowsVolume]Folder [WindowsVolume]\Folder\ etc. Still just goes through. It's like it's ignoring the condition for some reason. If it cant find the file I would think it would default to false. But the condition is just defaulting to true ... or something. Any more ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify. If I use [SystemFolder] or something and then look for the file, then the launch condition works like it's supposed to. But I need the C:\MYFolder condition.