# Folder property of File Search Launch Condition: how to specify custom folder under [TARGETDIR]?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project, orca, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to set a file search launch condition for my installer. I need it to search for a specified file in a subfolder of my `[TARGETDIR]` folder.

I tried setting the `Folder` property to:

- `[TARGETDIR]`/Subfolder
- `[TARGETDIR]`Subfolder
- `[TARGETDIR]`Subfolder/
- `[TARGETDIR]`/Subfolder/
- `[TARGETDIR]`/"Subfolder"

None of the above solutions worked. The file located in subfolder never gets found. It works if I only specify [TARGETDIR] with the `Depth` property set to 1, but I would rather specify directly the directory to search.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077626/using-a-custom-folder-for-file-search-launch-condition-in-vs-installer-vs-201), but there is no answer.

What is the correct way to set the `Folder` property to work with a custom folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that TARGETDIR is not set until later than the search is done, so it has no value yet. Even if if it did have a value, it's what is changed by the browse dialog that can change where the user installs thet app (see the property window of Application Folder in File System on Target Machine).

This means you must use standard folder properties in your search. If you want to search what you think may be where the file is installed, then use:

[ProgramFilesFolder]SomeFolder\SomeOtherFolder

or something similar if your assumed value of TARGETDIR is in Program Files x86.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to write a little console application that takes as input the installation folder specified by the user and search for a subfolder, and then set a property ? If it is possible, this step would be during the "Install" or "Commit" phase of the custom actions to allow the property to be set before the files are pushed in the folder ?

Comment: If you're going to write code then yes, that's possible, but if that file was installed with then a component search is preferable. There are plenty of ways of searching for installed applications other than a file search, so I'd encourage those. Registry items, upgradecode searches, componrent id searches etc.